# How i can retrive data from database with the conditions the data should be added before 6 month and the count of product should be above 200

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

The model query look like

```
$this->db->select('stock_id,product_name,purchase_date,purchase_quantity,sale_quantity,stock_status');
$this->db->from('stock_details');
$this->db->join('product_details', 'stock_details.product_id_fk = product_details.product_id');
$this->db->join('purchase_details', 'product_details.product_id = purchase_details.product_id_fk');
$this->db->group_by('product_id');
$this->db->order_by('purchase_date','AESC');
$this->db->where('stock_status',1);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

I need to get only the data added in 6 month based on `purchase_date` and the difference between `purchase_quantity` and `sale_quantity` should be 200

Comment: Thank you for edit by u_mulder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$this->db->select('stock_id,product_name,category_name,subcategory_name,color_name,size_name,purchase_quantity,sale_quantity,stock_status,DATE_FORMAT(purchase_date,\'%d-%m-%Y\') as purchase_date');

```
    $this->db->from('stock_details');
    $this->db->join('product_details', 'stock_details.product_id_fk = product_details.product_id');
    $this->db->join('purchase_details', 'product_details.product_id = purchase_details.product_id_fk');
    $this->db->join('category', 'product_details.category_id_fk = category.category_id');
    $this->db->join('subcategory', 'product_details.subcategory_id_fk = subcategory.subcategory_id');
    $this->db->join('size', 'product_details.size_id_fk = size.size_id');
    $this->db->join('color_details', 'product_details.color_id_fk = color_details.color_id');

    $where_date = "purchase_date < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)";
    $this->db->where($where_date);

    $where_quantity = "(purchase_quantity - sale_quantity) >= 200";
    $this->db->where($where_quantity);

    $this->db->group_by('product_id');
    $this->db->order_by('purchase_date','AESC');
    $this->db->where('stock_status',1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->num_rows();
```

Comment: This code is working well I'm  currently  using this code to fetch data from database to the given conditions

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
AND (PurchaseDate> DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND (purchase_quantity-sale_quantity)>200
```

DATE_SUB subtracts 6 months from your purchase date

Comment: not working the given query and thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @VishnuDas is it above or equal to 200?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
$this->db->select('stock_id,product_name,purchase_date,purchase_quantity,sale_quantity,stock_status');

$this->db->from('stock_details');
$this->db->join('product_details', 'stock_details.product_id_fk = product_details.product_id');
$this->db->join('purchase_details', 'product_details.product_id = purchase_details.product_id_fk');

$where_date = "purchase_date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)";
$this->db->where($where_date);

$where_quantity = "(purchase_quantity - sale_quantity) >= 200";
$this->db->where($where_quantity);

$this->db->group_by('product_id');
$this->db->order_by('purchase_date','AESC');
$this->db->where('stock_status',1);

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Than you for the support the given query is working, but a small correction for is i need to fetch the value of (purchase_quantity - sale_quantity) not exact 200 is should be above or equal to 200